# Unity3D - Get Touch Inputs but not on UI Elements

Tags: unity-game-engine

I interact with Input.Touches, but I also received Touch Events in my script. How it is possible to receive only Touch Events that are not fired on UI Elements?
Thanks for your help!
Regards,
Markus

Comment: Please edit your question and explain the problem. It's hard to understand what's going on. What are you doing and what's not working?

Comment: Please make this question more clear; it is kind of confusing and I don't understand. All you need is a little **rewording** then I can help!!

Also, I think it will be helpful to append some code so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Do a raycast check on Input.GetTouch and check if the object in question has been hit, if so run your code.